# chrome extension for setting default search engine

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for chrome, which sets a search engine as default with out any UI interaction(Edit search Engines). Is it possible to develop this kind of extensions. Is there any way such that I can override or use some functions in chrome source code.

Thanks
sathi.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible. The closest you can do right now is use the experimental [omnibox API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.omnibox.html) to register your own custom keyword.

Feel free to file a feature request at http://crbug.com if you would like to see an API like this in Chrome. Depending on your use case, there could be a better way doing what you wanted. Changing search engines isn't favourable without user intervention..