# Javascript/Chrome: Is it possible to access what's typed in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, search-engine

For experimental purposes, I want to create a bookmark in Google Chrome that functions like a search button by being able to access the current content in the address bar. Eg. I can type search terms in the address bar and click the bookmark, which will grab the search terms and pass them to a search engine.

I want to do this because I use multiple search engines and I don't want to go to a different search engine each time.

Edit: Please let me know if this isn't possible, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome extension for setting default search engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458248/chrome-extension-for-setting-default-search-engine)

Comment: its impossible with bookmark.

Comment: Mike Samuel: I don't want an extension. c69: okay, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser, If you exploit the browser then you can do this..